# Shipping matrix with multiple product vendors (location of product stock)

Tags: shipping, custom-options, locations

We need the following functionality. Could you please recommend a module can 100% fit our needs? I have seen some modules but I'm not able to determine from demos and docs if it really helps us with this problem.

We sell products that are located in the US and EU (2 different vendors). We sell worldwide. We need to calculate the shipping cost but we need to be able to set different shipping for different products. Few examples:

1. EU customer ordering only EU items -> 5 EUR shipping
2. US customer ordering only US items -> 5 EUR shipping
3. EU customer ordering only US items -> 10 EUR shipping
4. EU customer ordering both US and EU items -> 15 EUR shipping
5. India customer - if only US, he pays 1 shipping, if he orders EU and US, he pays 2 different shipping combined.

and so on. We have many rules for different countries, but every time there are 3 instances of the shipping matrix, based on the combination of products (precisely the location of products) and the customer location.

We might need weight rules too and free shipping option for some occasions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Shipping Suite** extension suits all your needs perfectly.

It is available for *Magento 1*: http://www.mageworx.com/shipping-suite-magento-extension.html

and for *Magento 2* (the module is brand new): http://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-shipping-suite.html

Both versions can do everything that you described and even more. On top of that, they are very easy to set up and configure.

You can configure shipping rules depending on zones and limit the available methods to EU or USA separately:

[image]
[image]

Also, you can select countries for each zone to ease further rules configuration. Each rule can be limited to group of customers or store:

[image]

Conditions are easy to use:

[image]

There are a lot of options to configure the shipping methods and their price:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure shipping method for above condition using [StorePep](https://www.storepep.com/) let me show you how:

Create a StorePep account and add your europian store as a vendor. You both will have a different dashboard to fulfill orders.

To set shipping methods first let's go to Admins account (in this case us vendors account).

Admins Dashboard:

1. Add shipping zones: I have added the United States and Europe for this case:
   [image: shippign zones]
2. Now Add new Rate Automation rule under shipping rate:
       i. Add a rule for condiction shipping zone United States --> Action: Flat rate 5 (your cart currency)
   [image]
      ii. Add a rule for condiction shipping zone Europe --> Action: Flat rate 10
   [image]

Now let us add shipping method in Vendors Dashboard: repeat the same steps as above only changes being Flat rate within Europe being 5 and to the United States 10 as shown in the image below: 
[image]
[image]

Now:
when EU customer ordering only EU items -> he will be charged 5 EUR  for shipping

when US customer ordering only US items -> he will be charged 5 EUR shipping

when EU customer ordering only US items -> he will be charged 10 EUR shipping

when EU customer ordering both US and EU items -> he will be charged 15 EUR shipping (the shipping charges will be added automatically in this case 5(for EU item) + 10(for US Item) = 15 EUR.

You can add more Automation rules based on your need. you can read more about [Multi-vendor here](https://www.storepep.com/shipping-guide-multi-vendor/).